# Git push fails within GNU screen

Tags: git, github, public-key, gnu-screen

I can push just fine to my GitHub repo from my VPS, but once I enter a screen, I get permission denied:

```
littke@[server]:~/src/[repo]$ git push
Pushing to git@github.com:littke/[repo].git
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Even though I'm able to auth:

```
littke@[server}:~/src/[repo]$ ssh git@github.com -i ~/.ssh/littke 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/littke/.ssh/littke':
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi littke! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Again, this only happens when inside a GNU Screen. I can push fine outside of it. I've googled but unable to find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a different identity file with ssh (the -i option) than git uses.  You must tell git which identity to use, through your config.  See github's [Troubleshooting SSH issues](http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/), section "SSH config":

> Create or open the file at
>   ~/.ssh/config Add the following lines:
>
> ```
> Host github.com
>   User git
>   Hostname github.com
>   PreferredAuthentications publickey
>   IdentityFile [local path]
> ```

Comment: This works, thanks! Why does it work outside of screen, though?

Comment: @JonatanLittke: There may be an interaction with environment variables or some other difference which you've not noticed and left out of the question.

Comment: Probably so! Meaning that may very well be the answer, too. But this works.

Comment: What if I'm connecting through my VPS, to which I've only forwarded my key (`ssh -a`). Can't specify an identity file, can I?

Answer (score 3):

`-i` is forcing ssh to use a different key.  When you try to use git, ssh doesn't know about that key.  Try using the default key name instead, or `ssh-add` the key so ssh knows about it.

Comment: I ran `ssh-add` within the screen and got `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`. This is probably related to the fact that the push doesn't work?

Comment: Probably.  Sounds like the screen session isn't able to talk to ssh-agent... which makes sense why you were able to connect outside of screen but not within.  Sounds like the above answer worked for you though, so I'd run with that.

Answer (score 2):

Some extra bits need to be set up to get SSH agent-forwarding working within screen.  Take a look at [How do you get screen to automatically connect to the current ssh-agent when re-attaching to an existing screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/180148/how-do-you-get-screen-to-automatically-connect-to-the-current-ssh-agent-when-re-a) for details on this.